# Twilio Functions : Trying to send incoming sms alert to handle STOP requests

Tags: function, twilio, twilio-functions

I am trying to send an alert SMS to an administrator phone number as well as replying to the original SMS with a local language version of the STOP response (we have turned off auto responses for this number).

The code below works for sending the response to the orignator - however, it does not send an alert SMS to the number we want (currently +447824636xxx).

I cannot find anything on the help docs, StackOverflow or Google Twilio dev group regarding how this might work in a Twilio Function.

Please advise how to get the highlighted code working.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {


console.log ("Incoming SMS")
console.log (event.From)
console.log (event.Body)

if (event.Body == "STOP" || event.Body == "Stop" || event.Body == "stop") {

console.log ("Received a STOP message")

// ***** BELOW CODE DOES NOT SEND SMS ****

// Send a warning message to Chloe
let client = context.getTwilioClient()

let c = client.messages.create({
      body: "We have a STOP message on Fresenius NO from ",
      to: "+447824636xxx",
      from: event.To
})

// ***** ABOVE CODE DOES NOT SEND ANYTHING *****

console.log ("Sent warning to Admin")

// Respond to the user/patient with STOP message in local language 
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
twiml.message("Du har nå meldt deg av MyFresubin og vil ikke motta flere meldinger fra dette nummeret.");
twiml.message.to = event.From
twiml.message.from = "+4759444xxx"
callback(null, twiml);
}

else {callback(null)}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work because you are calling the callback function too soon and will terminate execution prior to the call to the Twilio API being able to complete.

***Working code:***

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {

    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    twiml.message("Du har nå meldt deg av MyFresubin og vil ikke motta flere ....");


    let client = context.getTwilioClient();

    // Send a warning message to Chloe
    client.messages
        .create({
            to: '+447824636xxx',
            from: event.To,
            body: "We have a STOP message on Fresenius NO from " + event.From
        })
        .then(message => {
            console.log(message.sid);

            // Respond to the user/patient with STOP message in local language
            callback(null, twiml);
        });
}
```

Of course, feel free to add the `STOP` conditional statements you have in your original code.